# Row Number() Order Issue

Tags: sql, oracle, t-sql, netezza, row-number

Apologies in advance if this specific scenario has been asked previously, but I can't seem to get these to order properly (which is probably from staring at it for too long).

I'm using Netezza/Oracle, and In the data set below - I basically need the order_num to result in 1,2,2,2,2,3,4 (basically grouping Department and Desc1 (desc1 is not unique as there are different codes for each year, but I'm only interested in the type, not year).) Among other attempts, I've tried:

> row_number () over (partition by a.department order by desc1) order_num

Which orders it alphabetically. I've also ordered by seq_no and desc1 - but that only works if I needed it alphabetically.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Use `DENSE_RANK()` instead of `row_number()`

Comment: This gets closer but I need to keep the overall seq_no or beg_date order - just ordering by desc1 takes the overall order out of line.

Comment: Provide expected result

Comment: I don't understand why not just use SEQ_NO?

Comment: Just added the same data with an Expected Result column - I need to keep the data as is - just with the Expected Order list on the right. The dense_rank helps but compromises the overall order.

Comment: I need rows 2-5 to have the same rank # - whereas seq_no returns a different number for each row/

Comment: Sounds like in addition to `dense_rank` you need an `order by ORDER_NUM, SEQ_NO` or `order by SEQ_NO` on the `select` statement. The `ORDER BY` inside the `over` clause of `row_number` or `dense_rank` does not reliabily order the rows returned by the query. If you want a specific ordering on the returned rows, an `order by` on the `select` is required.

Comment: Agreed - I tried this method too - it does work in terms of ordering it properly but it keeps the dense_rank numbers the same (just out of order.) I need to break it out as the next step is taking the min beg_date and max end_date for each desc1 type to smooth it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the Country is consistent with the grouping as you have shown; if you get the minimum seq_no per country in either a CTE or sub-query you can use this value in your dense_rank function, e.g.

```
    SELECT 
       m.Department,
       m.Desc1,
       m.seq_no,
       m.Country,
       m.beg_date,
       m.end_date,
       dense_rank() OVER(PARTITION BY m.Department ORDER BY mintbl.MinSeq) 
FROM dbo.mytable AS m
JOIN ( SELECT min(m.seq_no) AS MinSeq,
               m.Department,
                         m.Country
        FROM dbo.mytable AS m
        GROUP BY m.Department,m.Country
     ) AS mintbl ON mintbl.Department = m.Department AND mintbl.Country = m.Country
ORDER BY m.seq_no
```

Comment: I think this one will work - just one minor change - rather than min(seq_no) and m.country in the join - using desc1 in place of country, and joining back on m.desc1 = mintbl.desc1 and m.department = mintbl.department will get me there. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You want `dense_rank()` rather than `row_number()`:

```
dense_rank() over (partition by a.department order by desc1) order_num
```

If you want to maintain the `seqnum` order, you can use a subquery to calculate:

```
min(seqnum) over (partition by department, desc1) as min_seqnum
```

Then in the outer query use `min_seqnum` for the `order by`.

Comment: Thank you - this gets me closer but the order by alphabetizes the list by desc1, rather than keeping the seq_no in order.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not use

```
dense_rank() over(partition by department, desc1 order by beg_date)
```

Or...

```
dense_rank() over(partition by department,desc1 order by seq_no)
```

Comment: This works in the sens that desc1 is ordered alphabetically - rather than by seq_no or beg_date. I thought about concatenating seq_no and desc1 but I run into the same issue.

Comment: If your SEQ_NO is ordered alphabetically it is probably stored as a string, which is a bad idea if it only contains a sequence anyway... you can probably fix it by a cast: .... order by SEQ_NO::integer ... but that assumes that the column only contains the 10 digits [0-9]